# Google App Engine logs do not load

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

We have multiple Google App Engine projects, all of which have been up and running properly, but one of our project's logging is currently not loading.

Has anyone encountered an issue were their Google App Engine logs do not load?

[image]

The query string on the url that automatically loads for the not working project is `&minLogLevel=0&expandAll=false` which does not match any of our other projects. When we manually edit the query string to match the projects that are working it still does not load.

Does anyone have a suggestion to how we can get our logs to load? The project that does not have logging working is a production version and we would really appreciate having logs back up.

Edit:
Can anyone confirm that the loss of our logging may be due to the changes on December 5, 2016? (https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing)

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Comment: @MeLight ...unfortunately we didn't find a solution. We just waited and Google magically brought them back. It has not reappeared for us so far but  if you have any different/new insights you can comment them below :) maybe someone will be able to tell us more